Is it possible to make NiFi Processor to run but pass through unchanged flowfile?
I have this particular use case where I need to call sql procedure using ExecuteSQL but instead of returning procedure result, I need to return exact same flowfile that entered this processor.
Is it possible to configure processor that it let the unchanged flowfile through?
Regards,
Damian

Use PutSQL instead and set the SQL Statement property to your procedure call.
